# Polling change on rails with railscasts revised

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to follow polling for change but i get the following error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object global] has no method CommentPoller
```

Here the code in my comment.js.coffee file

```
# Place all the behaviors and hooks related to the matching controller here.
# All this logic will automatically be available in application.js.
# You can use CoffeeScript in this file: http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/

@CommentPoller ->
  poll: ->
    setTimeout @request, 5000

  request: ->
    $.get($('#comments').data('url'))

jQuery ->
  if $('#comments').length > 0
    CommentPoller.poll()
```

What i am doing wrong?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the first line
from

```
@CommentPoller ->
```

to

```
CommentPoller =
```

Comment: The easiest way to understand coffeescript is to compare coffeescript fragments with the corresponding generated javascript. There are alot of instructive examples at http://coffeescript.org, and, even better, you can try your own fragments on the "Try CoffeeScript" tab. So type two variations of code into the browser (separately) and look at how the corresponding javascript differs.